# Induction Proof of trig inequality $\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k| \ge \frac n2$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, induction

**This is for a course, I don't want the answer just a prod in the right direction!**

I've got a problem that states

let n be an integer such that $$n\gt0$$  $$\text{Prove: }\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k| \ge \frac n2$$

I'm using induction to prove this. First I showed my base case:

When $P(0)$ $\sum_{k=0}^0 |\cos o| \ge \frac 02$

Which simplifies down into $|1|\ge 0$ which holds true. So I moved to the induction step.

Assume: $P(n)$ is true such that $\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k| \ge \frac n2$

WTS: P(n+1) is true such that $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} |\cos k| \ge \frac n2$

So I broke the summation up into two parts

$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} |\cos k|=\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k|+ \cos(n+1)$ Which I can substitute back in and get

$\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k|+ \cos(n+1) \ge \frac {n+1}2$

I know, well I think, that this is where I use my Induction Hypothesis $\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k| \ge \frac n2$

But I don't now how to show my next step.

Can I just substitue $\frac n2$ in for $\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k|$ and continue to solve? or do I have to show more steps in the middle? or am I completely lost? If anyone can prod me into the right direction it would be much appreciated! Thanks for your help!

***First Edit***
@Bungo

This is the way I've been doing it.
Is my logic wrong? Do I need to prove the lower bound? Or is my logic okay?

So I broke the sum down and re wrote it as $\sum_{k=0}^n + |\cos n+1| \ge \frac {n+1}2$

And then substituted from the induction hypothesis and wrote it as $\frac n2 + |\cos n+1| \ge \frac {n+1}2$

Then I simplified and got $|\cos n+1| \ge \frac 12$

So now I'm trying to prove that statement as true. Is this okay? Or should I go back and try with the triplets as you suggested? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have some typos in your first edit. Probably $|\cos n + 1|$ should be $|\cos(n+1)|$ (three occurrences). Assuming this, the problem is as I mentioned in my answer. You won't be able to prove that $|\cos(n+1)| \geq 1/2$, because it isn't true in general. Indeed, $|\cos(n+1)|$ can be arbitrarily close to zero. For example, $|\cos(11)| \approx 0.004$. I think the problem statement is still true, but in order to get a usable lower bound, you will have to consider groups of 3 terms as I outlined in my answer. Unless someone else has a clever trick...

Comment: @Bungo Am I trying to break the Sum down into triplets? I've never had to consider groups of 3 like this so I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: I think that's right. I plotted $|\cos(x-1)| + |\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)|$ and it appears to exceed $3/2$ for all $x$, so this suffices to obtain the lower bound $n/2$. However, it's not obvious how to *prove* that $|\cos(x-1)| + |\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)| \geq 3/2$ for all $x$, or even for all integer $n$.

Comment: @Bungo From talking to one of my professors he had the idea to take the sum from 0 to n-2 instead of from 0 to n. Would that make it to where I can put |cos(x−1)|+|cos(x)|+|cos(x+1)| at the end? Then If I'm able to prove that it exceeds 3/2 I'd have the problem in the bag right? Because no matter what the sum is before |cos(x−1)|+|cos(x)|+|cos(x+1)| it would always be greater than 3/2.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The tricky part will be proving the 3/2 lower bound. If you can do that, the rest should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: You might want to consider opening a separate question for just that part: how to prove that $|\cos(x-1)| + |\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)| \geq 3/2$, with the inequality included in the title. That might get some answers from people who haven't been following this thread. I'm not sure how to prove it, but it appears to be true based on the Wolfram Alpha plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}|\cos(k)| \geq \frac{n}{2}$$
appears to be true, but it is not in general true that
$$\frac{n}{2} + |\cos(n+1)| \geq \frac{n+1}{2}$$
(e.g., this is false for $n=1$). So I don't think it will be useful to decompose the sum as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} |\cos(k)| = |\cos(n+1)| + \sum_{k=0}^n |\cos(k)|$$
because we don't have a lower bound for $|\cos(n+1)|$ other than zero.

Instead, one might look at pairs of the form $|\cos(n)| + |\cos(n+1)|$ and try to find a useful lower bound for these. Plotting $|\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)|$ at Wolfram Alpha suggests that $|\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)| > 0.8$ for all $x$, which is still not good enough: we need a lower bound of $1$ if we add in pairs.

So let's look at triplets: $|\cos(n-1)| + |\cos(n)| + |\cos(n+1)|$. Wolfram Alpha's plot shows that the function $|\cos(x-1)| + |\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)|$ stays above $1.5$, so if you can prove that lower bound, breaking the sum into groups of triplets should suffice. I think proving the lower bound will be grungy, though. Hopefully someone can propose a nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Induction we do the following:

- Show that the relation is true for the case $k=1$, i.e., prove that $\mathfrak{R}(1)$ is true, usually by putting values.
- Assume truth of the relation for a general value of $k$, i.e., assume $\mathfrak{R}(k)$ is true.
- Show that by assuming truth for a value of $k$ proves that the relation is also true for $(k+1)$, usually by showing that $\mathfrak{R}(k+1)=f(\mathfrak{R}(k))$* and then putting the expression of $\mathfrak{R}(k)$ into this and then establishing truth of $\mathfrak{R}(k+1)$.
- If this is done, you have proved the theorem/identity by induction.

---

[*or in simple words, express $\mathfrak{R}(k+1)$ in terms of $\mathfrak{R}(k)$, let this correlation be denoted by $f$, usually but not always you get $\mathfrak{R}(k+1)=\mathfrak{R}(k)+\lambda$ or $f=\mathfrak{R}(k)+\lambda$]

---

Trying to use induction in this case:

- $P(1)$ is true.
- Assuming $P(n)$ is true such that $\sum_{k=0}^n |\cos k| \ge \frac n2$
- Now trying to prove that $P(n+1)$ is true using $P(n)$, or:
  $$P(n+1)=P(n)+|\cos(n+1)|\ge\frac n2+|\cos(n+1)|\ge^*\frac{n+1}2$$
  The $^*$ relation is not always true, so it's not possible to prove by this simple induction, you have to evoke something more complex.

---

If you are not bound to use induction you may use the result:
$$\cos\alpha+\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)+\cdots+\cos\left(\alpha+(n-1)\beta\right)\\=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\alpha+k\beta\right)=\frac{\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{n-1}2\beta\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\beta}2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\beta}2\right)}$$

Comment: The * relation is already false for $n=1$, because $|\cos(1+1)| = |\cos(2)| \approx 0.416$.

Comment: @Bungo I suppose the OP wants to learn induction proof writing, anyways copied your comment to OP's post

Comment: The OP's statement is true for $n=1$, but the one in your answer is false. I don't think it will be useful to decompose the sum as $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} |\cos(k)| = |\cos(n+1)| + \sum_{k=0}^n |\cos(k)|$, because we don't have a lower bound for $|\cos(n+1)|$ other than zero. Instead, it may be better look at pairs of the form $|\cos(n)| + |\cos(n+1)|$ and try to find a useful lower bound for these.

Comment: Sometimes one can prove $P(n)$ for all $n$ by means of an inductive step from $n$ to $n + 1$, but sometimes we have to do something more complicated. In this case, it's more complicated.

Comment: @Fmonkey, you may use this, see the edit

Comment: Your formula for the sum of the cosines is correct, but I don't see how it can help here. We would need its absolute value to exceed $n/2$ for all $n$, but this is impossible since it is bounded above by the constant $1/|\sin(\beta/2)|$.

Comment: @Bungo I have not tried using it, therefore said "may be useful"

Comment: @Aditya: Understood :-)